# I want to check my understanding about azure

Tags: azure

I would like to check my understanding of azure sas token.
we can access a BLOB storage using SAS token instead of azureAD certification. Does this mean that a person who does not have azure account can access a BLOB storage???
Or a person who has azure account can use SAS token and access a BLOB storage.

Comment: I would suggest starting with the documentation around Shared Access Signatures, as well as Stored Access Policies, to gain a better understanding of the different capabilities and access scopes, as there are different types of SAS tokens, with different permissions grantable to each, along with expirations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a person or script that has a SAS token can access BLOB storage, according to the permissions set in the token. That person or script does not need to have an azure account. Of course, that person would not be able to use the Azure portal to see the blob container, but he can access the storage account using programatically using the Azure API. He can also fetch blobs using HTTP GET requests.

As an example, I have a build script that pushes to storage and a deploy script to read from storage. These scripts contain the access token so they can run from any machine.

If I wanted to revoke the privileges of that access token I would need to replace the key that I used to generate the token with.

Comment: "If I wanted to revoke the privileges of that access token I would need to replace the key that I used to generate the token with." - that's unnecessary. Revoking SAS tokens shouldn't be necessary if you use a short token expiry. You can also use an "Access Policy" to define common permissions and to batch-revoke SAS tokens without needing to reset your storage account's primary and secondary keys. Access Policies can be set from the command-line or by any HTTP client that is using pri/sec keys (but not SAS, obviously).

Comment: @Dai Thank you for the clarification. They've added the Access Policy entities since I last studied it.

Comment: To clarify: It's not just that it's *unnecessary* to revoke a SAS token: You *cannot* revoke a SAS token. Also, regarding being able to access a storage account: Only a *Service-level* SAS has any type of service-level capabilities, and only if those capabilities are enabled. This is a very uncommon (and dangerous) case, where the common case is a container-level or blob-level SAS, which offers no access outside of that scope.